# what are the top conferences for Time Series Analysis and related topics?

Tags: time-series, conferences

what are the most relevant conferences for Time Series related topics?

- forecasting
- multivariate time series
- anomaly detection in multivariate time series

Answer (score 1):

### For anomaly detection in multivariate time series, ACM SIGKDD, IEEE ICDM and SIAM are all good venues (I have multiple papers on this topic in all these conferences).

### For "multivariate time series", this question makes no sense, it is not the data type, but the analysis that matter.

### For "forecasting", see [a].

However, these are approximate mappings. If you idea requires clear diskbase indexing, then SIGMOD or pVLDB could be good, if you have a clever application, then ICMLA might be a good fit.

[a] 2018 INFORMS International Conference in Taipei, Taiwan, 17-20th June 2018;
29th European Conference on Operational Research, Valencia, 8-11th July;
24th IIF Workshop ‘Forecasting for Social Good’, Cardiff, UK, 12-13th July;
13th Annual Behavioral Operations Conference 2018 (INFORMS BOM), 29-1 July in Cambridge, Massachusetts, USA;
OR60 in Lancaster, UK, 11-13th September this year;

Comment: ACM SIGKDD, IEEE ICDM, ICMLA are not dedicated to Time Series only. Roughly less than 10% are related to time series.

I recently found this ITISE 2018 (International conference on Time Series and Forecasting) [http://itise.ugr.es/] [http://itise.ugr.es/topics.php]. But I'm not sure if it is considered to be one of the top conf.

Comment: Sure, not "dedicated to Time Series only."   But the most cited papers on the topics of "anomaly detection in multivariate time series" etc are all published in those venues.